# Scalar multiples of a convex hull

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $A$ be the set consisting of all unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose coefficients are non-negative (they lie in the positive orthant). Then the set of all non-negative scalar multiples of $A$, i.e. $\{ \lambda a : a \in A, \lambda \geq 0 \}$ is the whole positive orthant.

Now let $B = \text{hull}( A \cup \{ x \})$ where hull is the convex hull and $x$ is a nonzero vector in the negative orthant (all coefficients are non-positive). Is the set of all non-negative scalar multiples of $B$ the whole space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $B$ contains an open ball centered at the origin.

Note that $-x/\|x\| \in A$. Since the origin lies on the line between $-x/\|x\|$ and $x$, it lies in $B$.
If $x$ has all components **strictly negative**, then you can "wiggle" $-x/\|x\|$ and consider the same line; that is, consider the line between $x$ and a point in a neighborhood of $-x/\|x\|$ in $A$ to show that a small ball centered at the origin lies in $B$. [This is a rough argument, and needs to be made rigorous.]

---

To see why the strictly negative condition is required, consider the following counterexample: dimension is $n=2$, and $x=(-1,0)$ or $x=(0,-1)$.
This shows that we cannot let $-x/\|x\|$ lie on the "boundary" of $A$, else we cannot get a full ball centered at the origin in $B$.